# Select the img src from the next list item for a next button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a beginner and driving myself crazy with this so I hope someone can help, or at least tell me that I'm barking up the wrong tree!

I am trying to implement next and previous buttons for a photo gallery using JavaScript (or jQuery; anything that works really!). The way I have approached it is by attempting to put the images into an ordered list and then extract the src data from the next item in the list, but it isn't working.

The html is something along these lines (the block div helps with positioning the images before the modal window opens and there are also captions within them as well, so it is not quite just a one-item, 'easy' list).

```
<div class="content">
    <ol>
         <li>
              <div class="block">
                  <img src="Images/image1.jpg">
              </div>
         </li>

         <li>
              <div class="block">
                   <img src="Images/image2.jpg">
              </div>
         </li>
   </ol>  
</div>
```

So basically, the modal will be showing the first image (image1), and I was trying to get the next button to find the next list item, take its img src (i.e. image2.jpg) and replace the current one with it.

Is this actually possible? The code below is kind of the logic behind what I've been trying, but I'm missing a couple of key parts unfortunately!

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
var i;

var next = document.getElementsByClassName("next")[0];

for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
       /*and this is where it all falls down!*/
        var indexNo = $(this).index();
        var nextIndex = indexNo +1;
        var nextItem = select the list item with the nextIndex;
    }

    next.onclick = function (){
        newSrc = nextItem.getElementsByTagName('src');
        modalImg.src = newSrc;
    }
}
```

And then I'll implement the inverse of this for a previous button as well.

As I say, I'm only a beginner so let me know if I'm trying to catch rain in the Atacama! Thanks for reading, I'm looking forward to anyone's input :)

Comment: Why don't you just assign an attribute to your images that will tell you the current index? Then getting the next/previous one is a matter of incrementing/decrementing an active image's attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Modify your markup a little:

```
<div class="content">
    <ol>
        <li class="image-wrapper">
            <div class="block">
                <img data-image-index="1" src="Images/image1.jpg">
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="image-wrapper">
            <div class="block">
                <img data-image-index="2" src="Images/image2.jpg">
            </div>
        </li>
   </ol>
   <button class="prev-btn">Prev</button>
   <button class="next-btn">Next</button>
</div>
```

Then you could do something like:

```
var imageCarousel = {
    totalImages: false,
    currentIndex: false,

    init: function() {
        this.totalImages = this.getTotalImages();

        if (this.totalImages) {
            $('.image-wrapper img[data-image-index]').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                imageCarousel.currentIndex = $(this).data('imageIndex');

                // Show the image here...
            });

            $('.prev-btn, .next-btn').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                var newIndex = $(this).is('.prev-btn') ? imageCarousel.currentIndex - 1 : imageCarousel.currentIndex + 1,
                    newImageToShow;

                if (newIndex > imageCarousel.totalImages) {
                    newIndex = 1;
                } else if (newIndex == 0) {
                    newIndex = imageCarousel.totalImages;
                }

                newImageToShow = $('.image-wrapper img[data-image-index='+newIndex+']');

                if (newImageToShow.length) {
                    newImageToShow.trigger('click');
                }
            });
        }
    },

    getTotalImages: function() {
        return $('.image-wrapper').length;
    }
}
```

And call the script, obviously:

```
$(function(){
    imageCarousel.init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it. Try and check if the code below works.

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
var i;

var next = document.getElementsByClassName("next")[0];

for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        /*and this is where it all falls down!*/
        //var indexNo = $(this).index();
        var indexNo = i;
        var nextIndex = indexNo +1;
        var nextItem = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[nextIndex];
    }

    next.onclick = function (){
        newSrc = nextItem.getElementsByTagName.src;
        modalImg.src = newSrc;
    }
}
```

---

If you are just trying your hands in JavaScript by doing this then its okay. But if you are actually trying to build something here, then I would suggest that you don't try extracting source and replace them to make a gallery. Try getting all the images/elements at once to the modal. Then on click transform/translate them from right to left or left to right using CSS3. That way you will also get a nice and swift slider. To implement that you will need to know more CSS than JavaScript/jQuery.

More over there is libraries [cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) for all your slider related needs. Use it to make things to faster and to get cross browser support.